# Error inflating class com.google.android.gsm (Admob)

Tags: android, eclipse, admob

I get some problems when I'm trying to add ads to my android app. I have added google-play-service_lib, but still get this error. Does anyone have any idea what I missed.

Activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffff00"
    >
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </ListView>

    <com.google.android.gms android:id="@+id/adView"
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         ads:adUnitId="a14e2f8fe3af5a6"
                         ads:adSize="BANNER"
                         ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR"
                         ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.appname"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.appname.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity 
        android:name="com.google.android.gsm" 
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />”
</application>
</manifest>
```

Stack

```
03-12 21:49:30.131: E/AndroidRuntime(31736): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-12 21:49:30.131: E/AndroidRuntime(31736): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.appname/com.example.appname.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class com.google.android.gms
03-12 21:49:30.131: E/AndroidRuntime(31736):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2304)
03-12 21:49:30.131: E/AndroidRuntime(31736):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
03-12 21:49:30.131: E/AndroidRuntime(31736):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:165)
03-12 21:49:30.131: E/AndroidRuntime(31736):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1326)
03-12 21:49:30.131: E/AndroidRuntime(31736):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-12 21:49:30.131: E/AndroidRuntime(31736):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-12 21:49:30.131: E/AndroidRuntime(31736):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5450)
03-12 21:49:30.131: E/AndroidRuntime(31736):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-12 21:49:30.131: E/AndroidRuntime(31736):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-12 21:49:30.131: E/AndroidRuntime(31736):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
03-12 21:49:30.131: E/AndroidRuntime(31736):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
03-12 21:49:30.131: E/AndroidRuntime(31736):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-12 21:49:30.131: E/AndroidRuntime(31736): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class com.google.android.gms
03-12 21:49:30.131: E/AndroidRuntime(31736):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
03-12 21:49:30.131: E/AndroidRuntime(31736):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
03-12 21:49:30.131: E/AndroidRuntime(31736):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
03-12 21:49:30.131: E/AndroidRuntime(31736):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
03-12 21:49:30.131: E/AndroidRuntime(31736):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
03-12 21:49:30.131: E/AndroidRuntime(31736):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:361)
03-12 21:49:30.131: E/AndroidRuntime(31736):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1956)
03-12 21:49:30.131: E/AndroidRuntime(31736):    at com.example.appname.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24)
03-12 21:49:30.131: E/AndroidRuntime(31736):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5369)
03-12 21:49:30.131: E/AndroidRuntime(31736):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
03-12 21:49:30.131: E/AndroidRuntime(31736):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2267)
03-12 21:49:30.131: E/AndroidRuntime(31736):    ... 11 more
03-12 21:49:30.131: E/AndroidRuntime(31736): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms" on path: /data/app/com.example.appname-1.apk
03-12 21:49:30.131: E/AndroidRuntime(31736):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
03-12 21:49:30.131: E/AndroidRuntime(31736):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
03-12 21:49:30.131: E/AndroidRuntime(31736):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
03-12 21:49:30.131: E/AndroidRuntime(31736):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:565)
03-12 21:49:30.131: E/AndroidRuntime(31736):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702)
```

Answer (score 1):

`com.google.android.gms`

Seems that there's something else missing in your path, try using the following:

`com.google.android.gms.ads`

Additionally, you seem to have missed the `activity` part for ads in your `Manifest` file:

```
<activity
   android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
   android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"` to `xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`

You probably got the other URL from an older tutorial.